# How to create global buttons and attach different handlers dynamically based on current visible view in WPF/C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF-Project with many views and each view has 8 footer-buttons. The footer-buttons trigger methods, that belong to the views.

I want to define the footer-buttons globally **once** and attach different click-listeners, based on the current view.

A little example to make it more clear:

The footer-buttons are created in the (parent) MainWindow. If I navigate to View1, the first button will get the label "Say Hello" and if clicked, it will show a message "HELLO". If i navigate to View2, the first button will get the label "Say Goodbye" and if clicked, it will show a message "GOODBYE".

[image]
[image]

How can I do this? What would be a good approach?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is using an interface and a user control with the buttons (only 3 here).
Window1 and Window2 is implementing the interface. The DataContext is bound to the user controls ButtonData property.

Each button has an index in the Tag-property. The Button_Click event handler is common to all buttons, but you can define one event handler to each button.

Don't forget and change the namespace in xaml.

Interface IViewButtons.cs

```
public interface IViewButtons
{
    List<string> ButtonNames { get; set; }
    void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);
}
```

User Control YourButtons.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp11.YourButtons"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp11"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="{Binding ButtonNames[0]}" Tag="0" Click="YourButtons_Click" Margin="5"/>
        <Button Content="{Binding ButtonNames[1]}" Tag="1" Click="YourButtons_Click" Margin="5"/>
        <Button Content="{Binding ButtonNames[2]}" Tag="2" Click="YourButtons_Click" Margin="5"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

YourButtons.xaml.cs

```
public partial class YourButtons : UserControl
{
    public YourButtons()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IViewButtons ButtonData
    {
        get { return (IViewButtons)GetValue(ButtonDataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonDataProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonData", typeof(IViewButtons), typeof(YourButtons), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    private void YourButtons_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((IViewButtons)DataContext).Button_Click(sender, e);
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp11"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="BtnView1" Content="View 1" Click="BtnView1_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5"/>
            <Button x:Name="BtnView2" Content="View 2" Click="BtnView2_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnView1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 window1 = new Window1();
        window1.Show();
    }

    private void BtnView2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window2 window2 = new Window2();
        window2.Show();
    }
}
```

Window1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp11.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp11"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:YourButtons Grid.Row="1" ButtonData="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window1.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Window1 : Window, IViewButtons
{
    public Window1()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void IViewButtons.Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;

        if (int.Parse(btn.Tag.ToString()) == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Btn " + btn.Tag + " pressed");
    }

    public List<string> ButtonNames { get; set; } = new List<string>()
        {
            "Say Hello",
            "Btn 2",
            "Btn 3"
        };
}
```

Window2.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp11.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp11"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:YourButtons Grid.Row="1" ButtonData="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window2.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Window2 : Window, IViewButtons
{
    public Window2()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void IViewButtons.Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;

        if (int.Parse(btn.Tag.ToString()) == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("Goodbye");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Btn " + btn.Tag + " pressed");
    }

    public List<string> ButtonNames { get; set; } = new List<string>()
        {
            "Say Goodbye",
            "Btn 2",
            "Btn 3"
        };
}
```

### EDIT:

Version 2:
I didn't observe that you wanted the buttons in the MainWindow. So this version has the buttons in the MainWindows XAML (No User Control needed). The same interface is used. Window1 and Window2 has no XAML but the same code behind.

You have to handle if the user open more than one window.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp11"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="BtnView1" Content="View 1" Click="BtnView1_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5"/>
            <Button x:Name="BtnView2" Content="View 2" Click="BtnView2_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="{Binding ButtonNames[0]}" Tag="0" Click="YourButtons_Click" Margin="5"/>
            <Button Content="{Binding ButtonNames[1]}" Tag="1" Click="YourButtons_Click" Margin="5"/>
            <Button Content="{Binding ButtonNames[2]}" Tag="2" Click="YourButtons_Click" Margin="5"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Bound to the buttons content
    public List<string> ButtonNames
    {
        get { return _buttonNames; }
        set 
        { 
            _buttonNames = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ButtonNames)));
        }
    }
    private List<string> _buttonNames;

    //Contains the current Window, used for accessing the windows implementation of IViewButtons
    IViewButtons currentWindow;

    private void BtnView1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 window1 = new Window1();
        currentWindow = window1;
        ButtonNames = currentWindow.ButtonNames;
        window1.Show();
    }

    private void BtnView2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window2 window2 = new Window2();
        currentWindow = window2;
        ButtonNames = currentWindow.ButtonNames;
        window2.Show();
    }

    private void YourButtons_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Forwarding the event to the windows event handler
        currentWindow.Button_Click(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @RolandJS , thank you so much. I could adapt this to my -a little bit more complicated- situation easily and it works like a charm. Thank you so much and best regards.